# How to find databases which accessible to me in Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to write a query which will give all the databases on the server which accessability to the user (read or more access).

Thanks,
Omkar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT name, HAS_DBACCESS(name) FROM sys.databases;
```

Comment: It also list system databases like master, tempdb. What to do if I dont want it ?

Comment: @Upendra you add a WHERE clause, like name not in (N'master', N'tempdb', ...)

Comment: Yes, I can add filter condition like you mentioned, but I want any column from which I can identify like these are system databases.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari sorry, there is no such column. You'd think there might be something in [sys.databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx), [DATABASEPROPERTY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176049(v=sql.105).aspx) (deprecated) or [DATABASEPROPERTYEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx) (surely on the way to being deprecated) but no such luck. You can exclude the four common ones by name, or using `WHERE database_id > 4` - however this doesn't handle things like ReportServerTempDB, the new SSIS catalog, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: OK thanks for your reply and valuable time. I will filter like that